# Who is calling the function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

In my application something strange is happening.

My controller has two functions, one to add a tab, one to remove a tab.

Here is the code:

```
$scope.createTab = function(){
         $scope.addTab("New Tab",50,0);
         console.log($scope.mbpTabs.length);
    }

$scope.deleteTab= function (index){
        $scope.mbpTabs.splice(index,1);
    }
```

I omit code for addTab, as I think it is not needed for my issue.

This is the structure of my tabs:

```
   <md-tabs class="stretch-height" flex md-selected="mbpSelectedIndex" md-border-bottom md-autoselect md-dynamic-height> 
    <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in mbpTabs" md-on-select="onTabSelected(tab)">
        <md-menu context-menu>
            <div flex class="mbpTable" ng-right-click="$mdOpenContextMenu($event)">{{tab.title}}</div>
            <md-menu-content>
                <md-menu-item >
                    <md-button  ng-click="deleteTab($index)" ng-disabled="mbpTabs.lenght<=1">
                       Delete
                    </md-button>
              </md-menu-item>

            </md-menu-content>
        </md-menu>  
        <md-tab-body>
                ...
        </md-tab-body> 
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab md-on-select="createTab()">
            <md-tab-label>
                <div class="mbpTable" >+</div>
            </md-tab>               
 </md-tabs>
```

when I select delete option from the context menu, after deleting something triggers `createTab` function (as seen in browser debugger). How can I find out what it is? I can't find anything in the code (I tried to perform a massive research of `createTab` command in the whole project, but I can't figure it out).

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Following the suggestion below, here is the calling stack of `createTab`:

[image: calling stack]

Seems like it is not my fault

**EDIT 2:**

It happens only if a new tab has been created already.

**EDIT 3:**

It works only under certain conditions:

1) Deleting a new tab works correctly (it doesn't create new tabs) only if tab has been selected before and it isn't selected at the moment.

2) Deleting a tab created on page loading works only if no new tabs have been created.

I still cannot explain it.

Comment: Put debugger in the createTab function and follow the stack trace in your console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `md-on-select="createTab()"`, upon remove old tab, this tab get selected. You can try bind this to another event.

Comment: this is not a problem, I'd like tabs not to be created when I delete one.

Comment: @IginoBoffa this tab get selected upon remove old tab and that trigger the md-on-select event.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is the problem because I need to check the rendered DOM, but you have unclosed tag `<md-tab-label>` that can cause blocks overlapping and can trigger both functions on click on deleteTab block.

Comment: Solving that issue, for every deleted tab, 2 new tabs are created